# Getting SSL Certificate has expired error in Laravel app, but it should should be valid

Tags: laravel, ssl-certificate, guzzle

I have an laravel app served with docker which until recently has been working fine, but since about 3 days ago it is not working. The problem is that I need to get data from a remote database, which is done with the guzzlehttp client used in the laravel framework. The SSL certificate is given automatically via. [Let's Encrypt nginx proxy companion](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion), and should be working, I have for example checked it on https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html, and it says the certificate is valid, but I still get the curl error "cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)".

I have tried manually to point the guzzlehttp client to the cerficate file, and even downloaded the latest [cacert file](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and used that, but no luck. Code looks something like this:

```
$this->client = new Client(["verify" => '/path-to-cert-file-in-docker-container.pem']);
```

Even more bizarre is that I have the same app running locally, and here I don't get the error if I use the certificate from the server or from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem mentioned above.

I should mention that we updated the let's encrypt container giving out the certificates on the server, so I run an older version locally. But the only thing that has changed is that we pulled a new image from docker, and I don't know what this should do to make a change here. I mention this since it seems that the error started after we updated let's encrypt, but I have been unable to find the connection.

Feel free to ask any questions or request code from the project.

Thanks in advance, Richard.